# Is adding user background (self-promotion) in some answers violating any policies?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-promotion

I was looking into a [certain answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415469/setup-stdvector-in-class-constructor/48846106#48846106) while finding solutions to my problem. I noticed that the answerer added a small 'My background' section at the footer of the answer. It seemed very innocuous and contains links to the answerer's GitHub, website, and YouTube, but I was curious and looked into the answerer's other answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172158/c-split-string-by-line/48837366#48837366), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484711/construct-object-from-vector-using-move/48846166#48846166)). Seems like the user have a habit of adding their background into some answers.

The '[How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)' page doesn't explicitly forbid this. The answerer doesn't seem to promote any particular product other than themselves, but I think that this is a possible self-promotion spam as it doesn't add any more information to the answer and should ideally be in the profile of the user themselves not in every answer.

Is this behavior against any policy? If so, what should be the course of action for this behavior?

Comment: Relevant is the [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) page in the help center: "**Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**"

Comment: It seems that all their newer Answers does not contain it.

Comment: Signatures are not allowed in answers, and they should be edited out. If you would *also* like to raise a "requires moderator attention" flag on one of the answers, bringing to our attention that you had to edit out a bunch of inappropriate signatures, and ask us to reach out to the user to tell them to stop doing this, then you are welcome to do that in addition to editing.